# How to apply ajax to get data in dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

i am using django as a backend to query my result.Like i have three dropdown and in my views I am using the value from first two drop down to bind the data in third dropdown.
I know i have to apply ajax but i am totally new to ajax call.By the way my desired data is comming in my views.

my views goes here:-

```
def send_notification(request):
    try:
        university_all_list = Universities.objects.using("cms").all()
        master_user_types = MasterUserTypes.objects.using("cms").all()

        university = request.POST.getlist('universityId')
        masterUser = request.POST.getlist('masterUserId')
        users = Users.objects.using("cms").filter(userTypeId_id__in=masterUser, universityId_id__in=university)
        print university
        print masterUser
        print users
        result_for_user =[]
        for list in users:
            result_for_user = list
            print result_for_user.name

        return render(request, 'templates/push-notification/push_notification.html',
                      {'university_all_list':university_all_list,'master_user_types':master_user_types
                       ,'result_for_user':result_for_user})
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        raise Http404
```

my html goes here where you can see i have three drop down named university,userType and users :-

```
<div class="clearfix margin_bottom30">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label text_left">University</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8 multiselect_container">
                                        <select class="mutisel" multiple="multiple" value="university_all_list.id"
                                                name="universityId"
                                                id="userName" required>
                                            {% for university_name in university_all_list %}
                                                {% if university_name.id == university_list.id%}

                                                    <option value="{{ university_name.id }}"
                                                            selected>{{ university_name.name }}</option>
                                                {% else %}
                                                    <option value="{{ university_name.id }}"
                                                    >{{ university_name.name }}</option>
                                                {% endif %}
                                            {% endfor %}

                                        </select>
                                        <script>
                                            $("select.mutisel").multipleSelect({
                                                filter: false,
                                                placeholder: "Select",
                                            });
                                        </script>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label text_left">User Type</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8 multiselect_container">
                                        <select class="mutisel" multiple="multiple" value="master_user_types.id"
                                                name="masterUserId"
                                                id="userName" required>
                                            {% for master_user in master_user_types %}
                                                {% if master_user.id == university_list.id %}

                                                    <option value="{{ master_user.id }}"
                                                            selected>{{ master_user.userType }}</option>
                                                {% else %}
                                                    <option value="{{ master_user.id }}"
                                                    >{{ master_user.userType }}</option>
                                                {% endif %}
                                            {% endfor %}

                                        </select>
                                        <script>
                                            $("select.mutisel").multipleSelect({
                                                filter: false,
                                                placeholder: "Select",
                                            });
                                        </script>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label text_left">User</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8 multiselect_container">
                                        <select class="mutisel" multiple="multiple" value="users.id"
                                                name="masterUserId"
                                                id="userName" required>
                                            {% for user in users %}
                                                    <option value="{{ user.id }}"
                                                            selected>{{ users.name }}</option>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </select>
                                        <script>
                                            $("select.mutisel").multipleSelect({
                                                filter: false,
                                                placeholder: "Select",
                                            });
                                        </script>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

i tried passing values values to context but i learnt somewhere it is posible through ajax call...pardon for my mistakes.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to retrieve some data to use in the third select?
You can do this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'The url to the view',
   type: 'GET', //Use POST if database modification would occur
   data: {
         'first_select': $('#first-select').val(),
         'second_select': $('#second-select').val()
   },
   success: function(data){
          //data contains whatever your view returns. If it's html, then add it to the select directly like $('#select').html(data); but if it's json response, Use it as you wish
   },
   error: function(xhr){
       alert(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
   }
})
```

I'd recommend that you add this just before closing the body tag on your page and not within the page. 
You may define some `{% block script %}{% endblock %}` in the base template that you've inherited and override that block to add your scripts in there.