# Update django template after object creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-models

I have a model package, and a table in the template that displays all the package instances, I want that table to be updated whenever new package instance is created without refreshing the page ( only new instances should be added ), after researches I found that ajax is the solution, also I have have read about django signal post_save, how  can I send the post_save signal to ajax in order to update the template ? thank you

Comment: You do not need post_save to update the template. Ajax is all you need. Read my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43766987/how-to-apply-ajax-to-get-data-in-dropdown/43770147#43770147
Just update the part of the DOM you wish to refresh from the success function. Your View must return `JsonRespons()`. and `JsonResponse()` takes a dict

Comment: @yusuf.oguntola ,Is there a way to launch the ajax request only when a new instance is created ?

Comment: If the instance would be created by an action from the same page the user is currently viewing, then yes. Save the db instance using ajax post and update the page on success. If the instance can get created by another means, then you may want to take a look at django channels (A blog here: https://blog.heroku.com/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django). Take note of the difference between web-sockets (As available in channels) and normal wsgi powered apps

Comment: Another option you may want to look at is django-commet: https://github.com/ziyan/django-comet